# Which finite simply connected spaces uniquely determined by their homotopy groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there an example of a *finite* simply-connected CW-complex which is the only *finite* complex with

a) given homotopy groups?

b) given homotopy Lie algebra?

In rational world we can make plenty of both types (and I think in p-complete too, though I'm not 100% sure), but I have no clue how one can prove uniqueness in non-localized spaces.

Comment: What about a point?

Comment: I'd rather have something a bit more complicated. Non-contractible to begin with.

Comment: Do you mean "is the only finite complex up to homotopy equivalence"?

Comment: It's very unlikely that any such examples are known.  I think that there is no known finite complex $X$ such that $X$ is not a $K(\pi,1)$ and $\pi_*(X)$ is known.  I think that the question is at least as hard as Freyd's Generating Hypothesis, which has seen very little progress in the last 50 years or so.  I don't believe that $p$-completeness helps.

Comment: It is possible if you put additional restrictions. For example, any Poincare duality space (of any formal dimension) that has the homotopy groups of $S^n$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^n$, but the argument is entirely rational.

Comment: Also probably relevant https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pi-algebra

Comment: @NeilStrickland Thanks for your opinion. I wonder where it becomes that hard, because (as Connor mentioned) as soon as we restrict dimension, we can show that spaces with few homology groups are unique in that sense (I can do it for spheres, complex projective spaces and $HP^2$ with requirement that we stay in stable range, ie they are determined by homotopy groups among complexes with dim $\leq 2n - 1$ with $n$ being dim of Hopf bundle sphere). So maybe we can push further, but how far that will go?

Comment: Two comments: (1) Just to be sure we're on the same page, note that if you remove the simply-connected hypothesis, then there are lots of examples of finite aspherical CW complexes -- tori, hyperbolic manifolds, etc. These are determined by their homotopy groups. (2) Given that you're trying to generalize something that happens rationally, it might be more natural to move up the chromatic tower and ask: When is a finite, sufficiently-connected space determined up to $K(n)$-local equivalence by its $K(n)$-local homotopy groups?

Comment: @TimCampion (1) Yes, simple connectedness removes examples where we know homotopy groups entirely (2) I had chromatic approach in mind thinking about my question, but I'm not so well-versed in these matters. I do not really see this as a "generalization", since in rqtional case uniqueness of realization comes from cdg model; p-complete spaces have Mandell E-infty model too, but integrally there are no usable cdga-type models (there are some unusable though).

Comment: There have been steps towards at least a Lie algebra -type model for unstable chromatic homotopy theory, though at this stage the relevant notion of "Lie algebra" is not quite as explicit as in the rational case. See the work of [Heuts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13055).